# Django 1.4 transactions to Django 1.8 transactions

Tags: python, django, transactions, autocommit

I have a function in django 1.4 project that saves model instance data into the database. say following is the view function

```
def view1(request):
    # processing request and saving model1 data
    model1.save()
```

There is some celery task running periodically that keeps checking for the data that just saved!! SO I wanted to make sure that the data in the function was saved and during that transaction the data would be saved and then it would be available to the celery task

so I did something like: what the below code did was, it made sure that the celery tasks were only executed if this following transaction was over

```
def view1(request):
    # processing request and saving model1 data
    with transaction.autocommit:
        model1.save()
```

Now, in Django 1.8,  I see that Django has changed it's autocommit behaviour, (is it?) everything now works in autocommit mode, what should I do now?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you were using `transaction.autocommit` before. Did you have code in `view1` after calling `model1.save()`, but you wanted to commit the transaction so that Celery could see the saved object immediately? Or did you save objects in the 'processing request and saving model1 data' section of the view, and you didn't want the transaction to be commited until you called `model1.save()`? Or something else?

Comment: Yes I have a lot of code after and before model1.save(). This after/before code actually makes celery assume that model1 exists in the database. so my trick was to open a transaction in autocommit mode. so my question is, if django runs in autocommit mode now, what should i do now? transaction.atomic()?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell its on by default now

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#managing-autocommit):

> Autocommit is initially turned on. If you turn it off, it’s your responsibility to restore it.

There are also [`atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) transactions where changes will only be applied to the db if there aren't any issues.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.6, autocommit was turned on by default. If you want to run a block of code in a transaction, then wrap it in an `atomic` block.

```
def view1(request):
    with transaction.atomic()
        # processing request and saving model1 data
        model1.save()
    # extra code that will run outside of the transaction
```

Once the atomic block has finished, Celery will be able to see the updated `model1` in the database, even while the extra code at the end of the view is running.